# Analyzing a CLR .dmp file in WinDbg

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg

I have a C# .NET 3.5 application created in Visual Studio 2008 that is crashing on a Windows XP SP3 (x86) PC with no development environment.

I have been able to get the .dmp file from the PC and take it back to my Windows 7 64-bit development PC and load it into WinDbg 6.12.

But, I can't see any code in the call stack from my C# application. It looks like it's entirely a native call stack.

The result from `!analyze -v` is below.

I have the relevant EXE, DLL, and PDB files in the same directory as the .DMP. The executable that crashed was compiled in debug mode.

I also have Visual Studio 2008, if that's easier to use. But opening the dump file in there also only shows a native call stack, nothing from my code.

How can I view the CLR call stack?

```
0:004> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


FAULTING_IP:
kernel32!RaiseException+53
7c812afb 5e              pop     esi

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  0392f018 -- (.exr 0x392f018)
ExceptionAddress: 7c812afb (kernel32!RaiseException+0x00000053)
   ExceptionCode: e0434f4d (CLR exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 80070057

PROCESS_NAME:  foo.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe0434f4d - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe0434f4d - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  80070057

MOD_LIST: <ANALYSIS/>

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
No export dumpstack found

MANAGED_BITNESS_MISMATCH:
Managed code needs matching platform of sos.dll for proper analysis. Use 'x86' debugger.

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 79ef2bfc to 7c812afb

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STACKIMMUNE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STACKIMMUNE

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STACKIMMUNE_NOSOS_CLR_EXCEPTION

STACK_TEXT:
00000000 00000000 foo.exe+0x0


SYMBOL_NAME:  foo.exe

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: foo

IMAGE_NAME:  foo.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4d5da0cd

STACK_COMMAND:  ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  STACKIMMUNE_e0434f4d_foo.exe!Unknown

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STACKIMMUNE_NOSOS_CLR_EXCEPTION_foo.exe

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: Minidump debugging for a managed program that doesn't use .NET 4.0 is very little joy.  It bombed on an unhandled managed exception.  Improve your odds to diagnose this by writing an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandedException and logging or displaying the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  Good enough to diagnose the cause of the trouble in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: @Hans - I was wrapping the code in Program.cs in a try/catch block, but this event is much neater. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Managed code needs a matching platform
>   of sos.dll for proper analysis. Use
>   the 'x86' debugger.

You would have to use the **x86 debugger/WinDbg** to debug an x86 memory dump. Use `.loadby sos mscorwks` to load the appropriate sos. You could also verify if the extension is loaded properly by using the `.chain` command.

[Tess](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx) has some good debugging tutorials.

Comment: @Naveen - My development PC is Win 7 64-bit. Can I use the x86 debugger or do I need to create a 32-bit VM to run that in?

Comment: Debugging tools for Windows x86 must be used (matching dump bitness). A 32 bit VM also works, but not necessary.

Comment: Once the dump is open and SOS is loaded, !CLRStack or !pe can show you the call stack or exception.

Comment: I went to the microsoft site to download the `Debugging Tools For Windows 32-bit Version` which lets me download the Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET framework 4. In that installer, I can only choose to install `Debugging Tools for Windows`. I don't have a choice between a 64 and 32 bit version. After installing, all I can find is `WinDbg:6.12.0002.633 AMD64`

Comment: Here is a link for previous version of windbg for x86 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463016#ERD

Comment: It is a shame that Microsoft makes things bad. You don't need the latest version in most scenarios, and a previous version should work. Besides, if you want to try the latest, simply download the SDK ISO, and the 32 bit installer is in it.

Answer (score 3):

[This tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx) is a good start to see some of the WinDbg commands. I think the following commands should show you the current stack trace:

```
.sympath SRV*d:\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
!reload
.loadby sos mscorwks
K
```

Answer (score 1):

Debugging managed crash dumps in WinDbg requires additional modules (primarily SOS.dll) and commands.

Some good starting links are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164138.aspx).

Comment: `.load sos` yields `The call to LoadLibrary(sos) failed, Win32 error 0n193`